# Как сделать GET запрос через JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, get

Как можно через `javascript` сделать GET запрос и получить от него ответ (html код некой страницы) ?

Например:

```
site.ru/index.php
site.ru/auth.php
```

Нужно в `index.php` приписать на js скрипт, что бы он сделал `get` запрос на `auth.php`, и получил его исходный код.

Через `XMLHttpRequest` можно? или как?

Comment: Да, можно через XMLHttpRequest. Просто прочтите это: http://xmlhttprequest.ru/

Comment: [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/), может?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GET-запрос обычно делается таким образом:

```
$.get("auth.php", {name_1:value_1, name_2:value_2}, function(data){
    ...код, выполняемый после запроса...
});
```

Можно передавать массивы:

```
$.get("auth.php", {'array_1[]':[value_1, value_2], name_1:vale_3}, function(data){
    ...код, выполняемый после запроса...
});
```

А на том конце запроса (в PHP) ловите как обычные данные из формы - реквестом.

По крайней мере у меня так работает.

Ответ из php, например html-код нужно передавать одной переменной. В JS вы его получаете под видом переменной data. С ней вы работаете в конструкции функции. Пишете свой код, вместо написанной у меня фразы `...код, выполняемый после запроса...`

[мануал](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-get/)